# how to set the index of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).index('.title'));
});
```

```css
.title{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorema</div>
<div class='title'>loremb</div>
<div class='title'>loremc</div>
<div class='title'>loremd</div>
```

Now, how to SET the index of a clicked element, i.e. change its position?

Is it possible something like:

```
$('.clicked').setIndex('.title', 3);
```

Comment: What is the actual behavior you are looking for? For example there are simple ways to move up/down one...or move to top/bottom without even doing any indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to `.remove()` the clicked element, then find the third `.title` element currently in the DOM, and use `insertAfter` to insert the clicked element after it:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.title', function(){
  const $this = $(this);
  $this.remove();
  $this.insertAfter($('.title').eq(2));
});
```

```css
.title{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorema</div>
<div class='title'>loremb</div>
<div class='title'>loremc</div>
<div class='title'>loremd</div>
```

Note the event delegation there - that's needed because otherwise, the listener will only work *once* for each `.title`.

To illustrate why `.remove` is necessary, check the following snippet - although it's using `insertAfter($('.title').eq(2));`, the `.eq(2)` refers to the 3rd element *before* the clicked one is removed, resulting in inconsistent behavior; if you click the first, second, or third element, it'll get put in the *third* position, instead of the fourth, as desired.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.title', function(){
  const $this = $(this);
  $this.insertAfter($('.title').eq(2));
});
```

```css
.title{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorema</div>
<div class='title'>loremb</div>
<div class='title'>loremc</div>
<div class='title'>loremd</div>
<div class='title'>loreme</div>
<div class='title'>loremf</div>
```

Comment: Yes, there is no need to remove the element. `insertAfter` will move it (not clone).

Comment: @puerto @Martin You have to use `.remove()` because without that, you won't know whether when inserting the element again, if it'll be at the correct index. For example, if you want to add something after index 2, behavior will be different if the clicked element originally exists at index 0, from if the clicked element originally exists at index 4. See new snippet